# google auth on electron app

Tags: electron, google-oauth

We are developing an electron app using and reactjs and node. Google oauth2 is being used for signup and login. But we are not able to get back to the app after successful login. What is the right way to solve this. What is the return url that is to be given to return the user to the app?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you opening the oauth window inside electron's browser window or operating system's default browser?

Answer (score 0):

Ajey, I am also working in the same project. We are using the electron react boilerplate (https://github.com/chentsulin/electron-react-boilerplate) to build the application. We are not using any separate window for authentication. When click on the signin button, the application will redirect to the google authentication page and redirect to the url provided in the "redirect_uri" parameter.